# How to end a process in python without ending the script?

Tags: python-3.x

ok, so I don't know if my title makes any sense, but I am extremely new to programming and I'm trying to learn by myself, so please bear with me. so when I launch a python script it opens a window, right? I type the command I want to run (my program is somewhat similar to a cmd) and due the the infinite loop, it runs the command over and over. The idea of doing this was to hopefully keep the window open once the command was run. Is there a way to keep this window open while still ending that command? because using any command like quit, exit, or break, ends the entire program and closes the window. sorry if this doesn't make any sense, I'll try to clear things up if need be. thanks in advance for taking the time to read this and for any ideas.

Comment: start a command prompt (aka shell window) and run your script there.  If the windowing system runs your python script, any window created for that will close when your script exits.

Answer (score 0):

You could put a statement like `input("Press Enter to exit")` at the end of your code (use raw_input instead on Python 2.x) - that would keep the program alive, and the window open, until the user is done looking at its output.

Or, you could open the terminal/command window first, and run python from the command line.  Exiting Python in that circumstance would leave the window open.